# Play framework how to parse object into a different structure in scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have objects as following:

```
case class Person(id: Identifier, age: Int)
case class Identifier(value: String)
```

If I use the default `Json.format` it will have `value` as property inside

```
implicit val identifierJson = Json.format[Identifier]
implicit val PersonJson = Json.format[Person]
```

Output(after parsing into Json):

```
{
    "id": {
        "value": "Foo"
    },
    "age": "20"
}
```

But the `value` property seems redundant to me, I want the following format:

```
{
    "id": "Foo"
    "age": "20"
}
```

How should I write my custom `writes` in order to get proper results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Identifier` type is quite similar to a `String` wrapper (BTW would rather make it a value class).

Combinators are available on JSON handlers:

```scala
val r: Reads[Identifier] = Json.reads[String].map(Identifier(_))
val w: Writes[Identifier] = Json.writes[String].transform { i: Identifier => i.value }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json, Writes}

case class Person(id: Identifier, age: Int)
case class Identifier(value: String)

implicit val writer = new Writes[Person]{
  def writes(o: Person): JsValue = Json.obj("id" -> o.id.value, "age" -> o.age)
}

Json.toJson(Person(Identifier("hi"), 5))
```

Comment: `new Writes[T] { def writes(v: T) = x }` is made easier by the provided functional factory `Writes.apply`: `Writes[T] { v => x }`